# What does $C_2^8, C_2^4$ etc in lattice diagrame of subgroup represent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lattice-orders

I am studying lattice diagrame of subgroups of groups. and I came to know about the lattices of $C_4\times C_2$ and $C_8\times C_2$ over [here](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~jwilson/math/8/C4xC2.html) and [here](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~jwilson/math/16/C8xC2.html).

But the problem is: I am unable to understand what does it mean by the powers in the diagramme? I mean to say, you can find $C_2^8, C_2^4, C_2^2$ etc in the lattice of $C_8\times C_2$ . Can you please help me to understand the meaning of it?

Comment: Any comment on this regard please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like $C_8^1$ and $C_8^2$ are the two cyclic subgroups of $C_8 \times C_2$ of order $8$, so the superscripts $1$ and $2$ are just labels to distinguish them.

In element lattice on the right we see that $C_8^1$ is generated by $(a,1)$ and $C_8^2$ is generated by $(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are the generators for $C_8$ and $C_2$ respectively.

Comment: Awsome and mindblowing. Its clear now. Thank you so much

Comment: Can you please explain me the following case of D12 http://www.math.colostate.edu/~jwilson/math/12/D12.html

Comment: @Anjan3 It would help if I knew what you were having trouble with. I'm not sure what convention you are used to, but here $D_n$ is the dihedral group of order $n$ not order $2n$. In the subgroup lattice there are two groups $D_2^{1,3}$ but presumably the one on the far right should be $D_2^{2,3}$, so that $D_6^m \cap D_4^n = D_2^{m,n}$. Also the element lattice has problems, for example $D_4^1$ apparently contains $b$ and $ab$, but $\langle b, ab \rangle = D_{12}$.