# How to create lattice diagrame in maple 14?

Tags: group-theory, lattice-orders, maple

I am studying lattice diagrame of subgroups of groups and I have already posted one query over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322564/what-does-c-28-c-24-etc-in-lattice-diagrame-of-subgroup-represent/1322588#1322588.).

Now my present query is: I am using MAPLE 14. Can anyone suggest me how to create lattice diagrame of subgroups in MAPLE 14 (if possible )

Comment: see here:http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjACahUKEwiIyqiMoYrGAhVEjSwKHVFrAHI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maplesoft.com%2Fsupport%2Fhelp%2Fview.aspx%3Fsid%3D2445&ei=PN56VYi8DMSasgHR1oGQBw&usg=AFQjCNHhsbUFXgWZlMw8iX0QV7dnMZ3yVw&sig2=vZa126OG-HjZ9oWlF0ivfg&bvm=bv.95515949,d.bGQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple's [GroupTheory](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GroupTheory) package, which contains a [SubgroupLattice](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GroupTheory/SubgroupLattice) command was [introduced](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=updates%2FMaple17%2FGroupTheory) in Maple 17 (released March, 2013).

That `SubgroupLattice` command can, optionally, return a graph structure that is understood by Maple's [GraphTheory](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GraphTheory) package.

Depending on your circumstances it might be easier to obtain Maple 17 (or later) than to implement this yourself in Maple 14 (released 2010). Perhaps you are eligible for reduced "student" pricing.

Comment: wow! that was really a helpful information . Thank you so much for it.